# Emberjs destroying component from the DOM from component code only

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I have created an emberjs component, which has a template and some code in js file. I want to remove that component from DOM and also want to remove all of it's events on some condition. How can I achive this ? or any similar way to achive the same ?

```
//app/pods/custom-comp/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
       if(some_condition) { //if this condition is true then destory the component from DOM and remove all of its events.
          //destroy the component
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: The easiest approach is to wrap the component if an `{{if` block.

Comment: @locks Yes using `{{if` block is an option. But it will increase the code in template. I wanted to remove the element from component itself.

Comment: It's two lines :P Even if you managed to destroy a component from the JavaScript side, it will mess up your application.

Comment: @locks I mean I have to do it at various locations. I got a solution but not sure whether it is correct or not. `this.$().remove()` in the satisfied condition

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/998456ae93e2db491c7a3776abebb4ba?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). I simply used

```
this.$().remove();
this.destroy();
```

and it seems to be working. However; I suggest wrapping with an `{{if}}` block instead of doing so; this does not sound good for me in terms of component design; but I am putting it as an answer since it seems to be doing what you want. Adding `this.destroy` will at least remove the observers for you and yet `didDestroyElement` hook will also be run; but not `willDestroyElement`. See [official documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_destroy) for `destroy`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just wanted to know, will it unbind the events and observers ?

Comment: @murli2308 I updated the twiddle to see if and observer remains; and yes it does indeed. The component seems to be removed from DOM but its observer still works; somehow Ember still keeps reference to the instance of component I guess.

Comment: @murli2308 even the lifecycle hooks such as `didDestroyElement` is not triggered with this method.

Comment: what if we call the methods from our code before destroying the component, like `this.willDestoryElement()` and removing the observers in that mehod

Comment: i updated the answer and added `this.destroy()`; this will remove the observers for you; `didDestroyElement` will be run; but `willDestroyElement` does not seem to be triggering. check the twiddle again please.